# Xcode: How to add Post Buld script insted of Run Script

Tags: xcode, xcode6

In the Build Phases one can add a phase by clicking the + button and get a menu showing a new Copy Files Phase, or new Run Script Phase.

The new phase is called Run Script, but in a related xcode project I see that there is a phase called Post-Build script.

I don't see how to add a Post-Build phase, only a Run Script phase.  Now maybe they are the same thing but it bugs me not to be able to see it called Post-build script and may cause some problem in the future.

How can I get the phase to be titled Post-build script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click the text "Run Script", and then you can edit it to anything you like.